# Insert multiple rows to MySQL with JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am a newbie to spring boot. I have two entities: course1 and course2 with each having a field code, for course code. I have been able to generate  select form fields due to entries  on couse1 database table so that input to course2 will be selected. However, whenever I make a selection on the form and post, all the selected course codes will enter a single field on course2 database table instead of each entering a separate row. Hence, my problem is, I want to insert multiple rows into a database table using JPA. Following is what I did and will be grateful if any body helps

## Course1 entity:

`

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "course_one")
public class CourseOne {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "course_one_id")
    private Long courseOneId;

    @Column(name = "course_code")
    private String code;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "courseOne")
    private CourseTwo courseTwo;
```

`
Course1 entity contains more fields describing each course though.

## Course2 entity:

`

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name="course_two")
public class CourseTwo{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "course_two_id")
    private Long courseTwoId;

    private String code;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_one_id")
    private CourseOne courseOne;
```

`

Course2 repository
`

```
public interface CourseTwoRepository extends CrudRepository<CourseTwo, Long> {

}
```

`

## At the service layer, the method I used to insert into the database table for course2 entity is:

`

```
public List<CourseTwo> saveCourseTwo(CourseTwo courseTwo) {
    return(List<CourseTwo>) courseTwoRepo.saveAll(List.of(courseTwo));
}
```

`
**This is my form:**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveCourseTwo}" th:object="${courseTwo}" method="post">
    <div class="overflow-scroll" style="border: 2px; height:dashed; height:300px; width:800px">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover" style="width: 100%">
                <thead class="green white-text">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Units</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="select : ${listCourseOne}">                            
                        <td><input type="hidden" th:value="${select.courseOneId}" name="courseOne"/></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="code" th:value="${select.code}" />
                        <td th:text="${select.code}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${select.title}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${select.units}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

However, the method inserts all the selected course codes into a single field. I will be happy if anyone helps.

I also tried to create wrapper multiple instances of CourseTwo as follows:

```
List<CourseTwo> lisOfCourse =new ArrayList<>(courseTwo);
   List<CourseTwo> courseTwoList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i=0; i<lisOfCourse.size(); i++){
       CourseTwo  courseTwo1 = new CourseTwo();
       courseTwo1.setCourseTwoId(courseTwo1.courseTwoId());
       courseTwo1.setCode(courseTwo1.getCode());
       courseTwoList.add(courseTwo1);
   }
   return (List<CourseTwo>) courseTwoRepo.saveAll(courseTwoList);
```

However, I get the following error: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface java.util.List

Comment: You will need separate method calls/inserts.

Comment: CourseTwo is a single instance, which means it is inserted in a single row. If you have multiple values in a String, you'll have to parse that out yourself and create multiple CourseTwo wrapper instances (or courseOne instances) to have them inserted into separate rows. I'd guess this is a problem with your forms, not JPA

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion you made for me. In case the issue is with my form as you suggested, I just added it for your input please.